# Spring batch does not start reading the list from the beginning

Tags: scheduled-tasks, spring-batch

I am using a Task Scheduler to run the batch job that runs after every 10 seconds. But, after every 10 seconds the reader begins the reading from 2nd element in the list.
My custom reader:

```
public class DataReader implements ItemReader<User> {

    @Autowired
    private MainDAO mainDAO;
    private int counter;
    private List<User> userList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.userList = this.mainDAO.getAllUsers();
    }

    public User read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(counter);
        if(counter < userList.size())
            return userList.get(counter++);
        return null;
    }

}
```

It always starts reading from 2nd element in the list while the counter must be set to zero when the class is created.
My Run Scheduler:

```
@Component
public class RunScheduler {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    public void run() {
        try {
            String dateParameter = new Date().toString();
            JobParameters parameter = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("date", dateParameter).toJobParameters();

            System.out.println(dateParameter);

            JobExecution execution = this.jobLauncher.run(job, parameter);
            System.out.println("Exit status: " + execution.getStatus());

        }
        catch(Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

My Spring configuration for Spring batch:

```
<!-- Spring Batch Configuration: Start -->

    <bean id="customReader" class="com.arpit.reader.DataReader" />

    <bean id="customProcessor" class="com.arpit.processor.DataProcessor" />

    <bean id="customWriter" class="com.arpit.writer.DataWriter" />

    <batch:job id="invoiceJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="customReader" processor="customProcessor" writer="customWriter" commit-interval="1" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Spring Batch Configuration: End -->

    <!-- Task Scheduler Configuration: Start -->

    <bean id="runScheduler" class="com.arpit.scheduler.RunScheduler" />

    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" cron="*/10 * * * * *" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
    <!-- Task Scheduler Configuration: End -->
```

Can someone please help me figure out what the issue is?

Comment: Your DataReader is Application Scoped. Trying making it step scoped

Comment: Thanks @KarthikPrasad. I read the docs to solve the issue and it’s the same as you’re suggesting.

Comment: I don't see bean definitions for your custom reader, processor or writer. They all need to be defined or is they are defined, provide them in the post.